# Is there a replacement/solution for `erewhon`?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

I am using the package *Fourier* for fonts, which doesn't work very well with `\textsc`. I have received a very nice suggestion to use the package *erewhon*. However, it requires font encodings that I don't have, like T2A and possibly others (the package requires also on T2B, T2C, and LY1; I'm not sure neither if all of them are required nor if I'm missing all of them).

Here's a sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{erewhon}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[68]
\end{document}
```

And this is an abbridge of the I get:

> $ pdflatex src.tex
>   This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
>    restricted \write18 enabled.
>   entering extended mode
>   (./src.tex
>   LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 1
>   Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 4 language(s) loaded.
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
>   Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/erewhon/erewhon.sty
>   `erewhon' v1.05, 2016/02/05 Style file for Erewhon (m_sharpe), based on Heurist
>   ica (a_panov) and, ultimately, Utopia.
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
>
> ! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `t2aenc.def' not found.
>   (fontenc)                You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.

Please note that the issue is **not** that I have not a `\usepackage{fontenc}` in my preamble. The package loads the encodings by itself. The issue is that I do not have the encodings it requires.

So is there a replacement for *erewhon*? Or perhaps is there a way to make it work with **only** the T1 font encoding?

I could certainly install the missing encodings, but I'd rather stick with what my distribution defaults to. That means less trouble when sharing LaTeX code with co-workers.

Comment: Just skimming the manual for it, doesn't it say that it supports those font encodings including T1, so what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Your TeX distribution is incomplete. I can't find a reason for the package to require the Cyrillic encodings, but this should be easily solved if you tell what TeX distribution you're using.

Comment: @egreg the log says tl16 debian

Comment: I'd say `apt-get install texlive-lang-cyrillic`

Comment: I'd like a solution that does not involve installing packages. So far I'm going with the following workaround: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\textsc}[1] {{\usefont{T1}{erewhon-TLF}{m}{sc}\selectfont #1}}`. This only does part of Erewhon's job, so it's suboptimal. I'd be happy with better suggestions...

Comment: The first significant line in `erewhon.sty` is `\RequirePackage[T2A,T2B,T2C,LY1,T1]{fontenc}`, so I think the only good solution is to [abide by its expectations](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/erewhon/) and install what is expected of the user or use the OTF with the XeTeX or LuaTeX engines. ... Or, note that Erewhon is an enhancement of [Heuristica](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/heuristica/) (but same problem with required font encodings), which is an extension of the Utopia font family, which can be used with or [without](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/utopia-mathdesign/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that doing

```
apt-get install texlive-lang-cyrillic
```

should solve the issue.

On the other hand, the last version of `erewhon.sty` (version 1.072, released 2017/02/21) has removed the dependency on Cyrillic encodings.